# Демон в java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class Ororo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyThread mt= new MyThread();
    mt.setDaemon(true);
    mt.start();
    MyThread mt2= new MyThread();
    mt2.setDaemon(false);
    mt2.start();

    return;
}
}
```

*MyThread* расширяет класс *Thread* и переопределяет так:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("MyThread runs" + currentThread().getId());

    }
}
}
```

После завершшения главного потока, два *моих* - продолжают работать. Почему работает 1 поток, он ведь демон!

PS возможно, что логика тут такова: Когда процесс *JVM* попадает в состояние, что в нем остались только демоны-потоки(фоновые), он их удаляет и удаляется сам. Когда процесс *JVM* попадает в состояние, что в нем есть хотя бы 1 не-демон поток(не фоновый), процесс не удаляется и соответственно демоны насильно удаляться не будут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [доках](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29)  же написано, что когда остались только демоны: JVM закрывается.

Comment: о точно, спасибо